# alternatives for Implementing a scheduler with resource view in Meteor

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

We are working a scheduling system for employees we achieved good results using a hacked version of fullcalendar that has a resource view , but we were constrained to put the whole FullCalendar init code in an autoRun block , since there was no working function that allows yuo to refetch resources or just add it programmaticaly , resources could only be added in the init Code , thus we destroy every time the calendar and recreate one on every change rerunning autoRun.

this resulted in bad performing scheduler .
now we are studuying the alternatives to revamp it .
the scheduler should support resource view and also should be used in a 2 weeks view .
what are the solutions available to avoid a from scratsh dev?

Answer (score -1):

Your assumptions are incorrect. You can use FullCalendar to do every thing that you mentioned.
You can see how to re-fetch [in the documentations](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/refetchResources/).
Also you can add events programmaticaly with the addResource function - [see documentation here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/addResource/).

If you initialize every time of course it will cause bad performing, but you are using it wrong. This whole plugin works with ajax and the performance suppose to be depended only on your server handling.

> Last thing, you said "hacked version" of full calendar.

FullCalendar is an open source project, so there is no "hacked", only the latest version... You can download it [here](http://fullcalendar.io/download/).

Comment: the scheduler part isn't included in this version of fullcalendar . it's paid.

Comment: yes the scheduler is paid, but it is a one time payment, not so expensive (the developer hours will probably cost you more if you'll start something new) and you'll get 1 year official support. sounds good to me